# C# - Need to retrieve data from 2 tables(cannot use join)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am making an attendance management system where users/employees can mark their attendance once a day. The admin can see the overall attendance of the employees. I have to show this in a tabular form.

I have made 2 tables in SSMS: `tblUser` and `tblAttendence`. `tblUser` contains `RegNo`(`int`), `Name`(`varchar`) and `JoiningDate`(`date`). `tblAttendence` has `DateAndTime`(`datetime`) and `RegNo`(`int`) as columns. So whenever a user opens the application and marks the attendance, it will be recorded in `tblAttendance` with the current DateTime and the RegNo of the user.

Now, I have to display this using a `DataGridView` with the columns as `RegNo`, `Name` and `Attendance`(this will be the number of entries found in `tblAttendance` corresponding to the `RegNo`)

Can this be done? I can't seem to find out a way to do this. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: why not to use join?

Comment: Joins exist for this exact purpose. If you cannot use join then you should explain why you cannot use the sql in way it has been designed to work

Comment: What query did you try to write? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: @Steve I have to display the no. of entries of a particular RegNo in `tblAttendance` and my professor said that since there will be multiple entries of that `RegNo` in the table, it cannot be used as the condition. I am a beginner in sql. So, if it can be done with join, can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the count of the attendances by user with

```
SELECT u.RegNo, u.Name, Count(t.RegNo) AS Attendance
FROM tblUser u JOIN tblAttendance t ON u.RegNo = t.RegNo
GROUP BY u.RegNo, u.Name
```

and if you like an order you can add

```
ORDER BY Count(t.RegNo) DESC
```